# Typing Text Page Load

Tags: jquery, html, css, loader

```
var speed = 'speed';   

$(window).load(function() {
    $("div").fadeOut(speed, function() {
        $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div").fadeIn(speed, function() {
                window.location = url;
            });a
        });
    });
}); 

// tipewriter by roXon //

var $el = $('p'),
    txt = $el.text(),
    txtLen = txt.length,
    timeOut,
    char = 0;

(function typeIt() {   
    var humanize = Math.round(100);
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $el.text(type);
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}());
```

I have a page loader and a text inside it.

What I want : When the loading is end, the text is typed. So, the time of typing depend of the the time of the loader.

**MY JS : http://jsfiddle.net/37bLhm80/1/**

Comment: There's no way to know how long it takes to load a page in javascript, it depends on connection speed, browsers, content etc. so what you're asking is impossible

Comment: We can't do that like a progress bar ?

Comment: Almost every progress you see on the web is fake, or it has some event driven system where partial loading is detected, for instance 4/6 images have been loaded etc, or it's Flash, where you to some degree actually can do this. Either way, in javascript you can't really know how long a page takes to load, until it's loaded